Ports closing to incoming traffic
I have a clean install of Ubuntu 24.04 on a cloud server to run iRedMail 1.7.1.
The server shows
sudo ufw status verbose
Status: inactive

and
$ ss -ltn
.
.
LISTEN       0            511                      0.0.0.0:443                      0.0.0.0:*                        
.
.
.

but from an external machine I get
Nmap scan report for xx.xx.xx.xx
Host is up (0.023s latency).
Not shown: 990 filtered tcp ports (no-response)
PORT    STATE  SERVICE
22/tcp  open   ssh
25/tcp  closed smtp
80/tcp  closed http
110/tcp closed pop3
143/tcp closed imap
443/tcp closed https
465/tcp closed smtps
587/tcp closed submission
993/tcp closed imaps
995/tcp closed pop3s

If I issue
server:~$ sudo ufw disable
Firewall stopped and disabled on system startup
server:~$ sudo shutdown -r now

then on restart I get
Nmap scan report for xx.xx.xx.xx
Host is up (0.011s latency).
Not shown: 990 filtered tcp ports (no-response)
PORT    STATE SERVICE
22/tcp  open  ssh
25/tcp  open  smtp
80/tcp  open  http
110/tcp open  pop3
143/tcp open  imap
443/tcp open  https
465/tcp open  smtps
587/tcp open  submission
993/tcp open  imaps
995/tcp open  pop3s

as expected.  It lasts a couple of minutes and something kicks the ports to closed again.  UFW still shows as Inactive.
What might be causing this behaviour?
Based on the delay before ports close, it may be related to
How to fix automatic apply of netplan config after reboot not working?
and the netplan generator?
Responding to mpboden, I am immediately concerned with 443, but NMAP shows ports either open or filtered when trying to communicate through an HTTPS interface.  My Netplan config is
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
      eth0:
          dhcp4: no
          addresses: [xx.xx.xx.xx/24]
          routes:
              - to: default
                via: xx.xx.xx.xx          
          nameservers:
              addresses: [8.8.8.8, 208.67.222.222]

I have not found any clues in the log files, but that may be my failure to spot something significant.
Addressing Thomas Ward's point, I have tried explicitly opening the ports in UFW, see Ports open in UFW but still shut to the outside world but it makes no difference.  I therefore have UFW set inactive, at least until I figure this out.
The delay suggests that some other Netplan component might be running asynchronously and changing the port configurations. But where to look?
I have set up another server that is working properly for comparison.  The problem seems to be associated with a failure to start systemd-networkd-wait-online.service.  Running a check (systemctl status ) on  postfix, dovecot & nginx gives "Warning: some journal files were not opened due to insufficient permissions." for all 3.  The working server does not have this warning.  I have started to go through the files in the /etc/postfix (etc) folders to compare permissions.  Would it help to list the status files here?
After comparing the systemd-networkd-wait-online.service between the physical (working) server and the (problematic) virtual server the virtual server contained these lines:
$ sudo systemctl edit systemd-networkd-wait-online.service
### Editing /etc/systemd/system/systemd-networkd-wait-online.service.d/override.conf
### Anything between here and the comment below will become the contents of the drop-in file

[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-networkd-wait-online -i enp0s3:degraded --timeout=30

### Edits below this comment will be discarded

The physical server did not have these non-comment lines, so I deleted them on the virtual server.  They have been re-inserted.
I also checked the Netplan configuration:
$ sudo netplan --debug apply

** (generate:73362): DEBUG: 09:58:53.126: starting new processing pass
** (generate:73362): DEBUG: 09:58:53.127: eth0: adding new route
** (generate:73362): DEBUG: 09:58:53.127: We have some netdefs, pass them through a final round of validation
** (generate:73362): DEBUG: 09:58:53.127: eth0: setting default backend to 1
** (generate:73362): DEBUG: 09:58:53.127: Configuration is valid
** (generate:73362): DEBUG: 09:58:53.128: Generating output files..
** (generate:73362): DEBUG: 09:58:53.128: Open vSwitch: definition eth0 is not for us (backend 1)
** (generate:73362): DEBUG: 09:58:53.128: NetworkManager: definition eth0 is not for us (backend 1)
DEBUG:netplan generated networkd configuration changed, reloading networkd
DEBUG:Cannot call Open vSwitch: Cannot apply OVS cleanup: ovsdb-server.service is 'not-found'.
DEBUG:no netplan generated NM configuration exists
** (process:73361): DEBUG: 09:58:53.607: starting new processing pass
** (process:73361): DEBUG: 09:58:53.608: eth0: adding new route
** (process:73361): DEBUG: 09:58:53.608: We have some netdefs, pass them through a final round of validation
** (process:73361): DEBUG: 09:58:53.608: eth0: setting default backend to 1
** (process:73361): DEBUG: 09:58:53.608: Configuration is valid
DEBUG:Merged config:
b''
DEBUG:Link changes: {}
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for lo
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for eth0
** (process:73361): DEBUG: 09:58:53.749: starting new processing pass
** (process:73361): DEBUG: 09:58:53.750: eth0: adding new route
** (process:73361): DEBUG: 09:58:53.751: We have some netdefs, pass them through a final round of validation
** (process:73361): DEBUG: 09:58:53.751: eth0: setting default backend to 1
** (process:73361): DEBUG: 09:58:53.751: Configuration is valid
DEBUG:Merged config:
b''

Then
$ sudo networkctl status

● Interfaces: 1, 2
       State: routable                        
Online state: online                          
     Address: xx.xx.xx.xx on eth0
              xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx on eth0
     Gateway: xx.xx.xx.xx on eth0
         DNS: 8.8.8.8
              208.67.222.222

Nov 25 17:00:42 example.com systemd-networkd[667]: eth0: found matching network '/run/systemd/network/10-netplan-eth0.network', based on potentially unpredictable interface name.
Nov 25 17:00:42 example.com systemd[1]: Starting systemd-networkd-wait-online.service - Wait for Network to be Configured...
Nov 25 17:00:43 example.com systemd-networkd[667]: eth0: Gained IPv6LL
Nov 25 17:01:12 example.com systemd[1]: systemd-networkd-wait-online.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 25 17:01:12 example.com systemd[1]: systemd-networkd-wait-online.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 25 17:01:12 example.com systemd[1]: Failed to start systemd-networkd-wait-online.service - Wait for Network to be Configured.
Nov 25 17:35:12 example.com systemd[1]: Starting systemd-networkd-wait-online.service - Wait for Network to be Configured...
Nov 25 17:35:42 example.com systemd[1]: systemd-networkd-wait-online.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 25 17:35:42 example.com systemd[1]: systemd-networkd-wait-online.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 25 17:35:42 example.com systemd[1]: Failed to start systemd-networkd-wait-online.service - Wait for Network to be Configured.

Then checking Postfix, Dovecot & nginx
$ systemctl status postfix
● postfix.service - Postfix Mail Transport Agent
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/postfix.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Mon 2024-11-25 17:55:25 UTC; 20min ago
       Docs: man:postfix(1)
    Process: 1875 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 1875 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 4ms

Warning: some journal files were not opened due to insufficient permissions.

$ systemctl status dovecot
● dovecot.service - Dovecot IMAP/POP3 email server
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/dovecot.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2024-11-25 17:55:20 UTC; 23min ago
       Docs: man:dovecot(1)
             https://doc.dovecot.org/
   Main PID: 719 (dovecot)
     Status: "v2.3.21 (47349e2482) running"
      Tasks: 17 (limit: 3481)
     Memory: 33.8M (peak: 40.8M)
        CPU: 552ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/dovecot.service
             ├─ 719 /usr/sbin/dovecot -F
             ├─ 732 dovecot/lmtp -L
             ├─ 733 dovecot/anvil
             ├─ 734 dovecot/log
             ├─ 735 dovecot/lmtp -L
             ├─ 736 dovecot/lmtp -L
             ├─ 737 dovecot/lmtp -L
             ├─ 738 dovecot/lmtp -L
             ├─ 740 dovecot/config
             ├─ 747 dovecot/stats
             ├─4383 dovecot/auth
             ├─4387 dovecot/auth -w
             ├─4388 dovecot/auth -w
             ├─4395 dovecot/dict
             ├─4396 dovecot/dict
             ├─4407 dovecot/imap-login
             └─4413 dovecot/imap

Warning: some journal files were not opened due to insufficient permissions.


$ systemctl status nginx
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2024-11-25 17:55:20 UTC; 25min ago
       Docs: man:nginx(8)
    Process: 741 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 838 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 859 (nginx)
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 3481)
     Memory: 5.0M (peak: 5.3M)
        CPU: 409ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
             ├─859 "nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;"
             └─860 "nginx: worker process"

Warning: some journal files were not opened due to insufficient permissions.

Finally, I found that the system works as expected unless I use Roundcube, which closes the ports again.  If I only access the e-mail through imap, the ports stay open.
I'll take that back.  It was open for a while, then closed again.  In fact, over a few hours it comes and goes.  Might this be a conflict of two components trying to control the network?
I have no idea where the override file for systemd-networkd-wait-online.service came from.  I tried deleting the three active lines, but they just popped back into existence next time I looked.
The status files give:
$ networkctl status eth0
● 2: eth0
                   Link File: /usr/lib/systemd/network/99-default.link
                Network File: /run/systemd/network/10-netplan-eth0.network
                       State: routable (configured)
                Online state: online                                                                       
                        Type: ether
                        Path: pci-0000:00:12.0
                      Driver: virtio_net
                      Vendor: Red Hat, Inc.
                       Model: Virtio network device
           Alternative Names: enp0s18
                              ens18
            Hardware Address: 00:16:3e:0b:31:2b (Xensource, Inc.)
                         MTU: 1500 (min: 68, max: 65535)
                       QDisc: fq_codel
IPv6 Address Generation Mode: eui64
    Number of Queues (Tx/Rx): 1/1
            Auto negotiation: no
                     Address: xx.xx.xx.xx
                              xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
                     Gateway: xx.xx.xx.xx
                         DNS: 8.8.8.8
                              208.67.222.222
           Activation Policy: up
         Required For Online: yes
           DHCP6 Client DUID: DUID-EN/Vendor:0000ab11e96dc6ba966458ee
                Connected To: kv0632-185-127-18-185.localdomain.local on port d2:6f:9b:c0:5b:55 (tap2010i0)

and
$ networkctl status enp0s3
Interface "enp0s3" not found.

I have modified the override file with eth0 because I still can't remove these lines.  Its running now, but time will tell.
This has fixed the problem.   Huge thank you to mpboden, especially for the lucid explanation of the problem given below.
I spoke too soon.  Having been up for just over 24 hrs, the ports have all slammed shut again.
From a different machine:
% nmap taid.info
Starting Nmap 7.95 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2024-11-28 16:22 GMT
Nmap scan report for example.com (xx.xx.xx.xx)
Host is up (0.021s latency).
Not shown: 990 filtered tcp ports (no-response)
PORT    STATE  SERVICE
22/tcp  open   ssh
25/tcp  closed smtp
80/tcp  closed http
110/tcp closed pop3
143/tcp closed imap
443/tcp closed https
465/tcp closed smtps
587/tcp closed submission
993/tcp closed imaps
995/tcp closed pop3s

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 35.61 seconds

and from the virtual server
$ networkctl status
● Interfaces: 2, 1
       State: routable                        
Online state: online                          
     Address: xx.xx.xx.xx on eth0
              xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx on eth0
     Gateway: xx.xx.xx.xx on eth0
              xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx on eth0
         DNS: 8.8.8.8
              208.67.222.222

Sigh ...

Are you talking specifically about port 443 or all ports listed in output of nmap? Have you checked the status of the services on those ports after they're supposedly "closed"? If you're suspecting an issue with Netplan, why not provide your Netplan config? Are there any clues in your log files?

Ports will only show as 'open' if you have permitted traffic through the firewall.  Even so, you have to have services running on those ports to really see them as 'open'.

You haven't answered either of our questions related to the status of of the services running on those ports. Please provide that.

iRedMail installs several packages such as Postfix, Dovecot, and NGINX. Therefore, check their status with systemctl status postfix, systemctl status dovecot, and systemctl status nginx.

Why is there an override file for systemd-networkd-wait-online.service? Did you create this? Or was it created by your cloud provider? Also, your network interface name in your Netplan config is eth0, yet in this override file it's listed as enp0s3. Why? Could this be a problem? Meanwhile, please provide the output of networkctl status eth0 and networkctl status enp0s3.

You've indicated that an override file exists for systemd-networkd-wait-online:
/etc/systemd/system/systemd-networkd-wait-online.service.d/override.conf

In that file you have the following. Notice that it's adding the network interface to the command, enp0s3.
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-networkd-wait-online -i enp0s3:degraded --timeout=30

In the manpage for systemd-networkd-wait-online.service(8), it states the following.

       --interface=INTERFACE[:MIN_OPERSTATE[:MAX_OPERSTATE]]
           Network interface to wait for before deciding if the system is online. This is useful
           when a system has several interfaces which will be configured, but a particular one is
           necessary to access some network resources. When used, all other interfaces are
           ignored. This option may be used more than once to wait for multiple network
           interfaces. When this option is specified multiple times, then
           systemd-networkd-wait-online waits for all specified interfaces to be online.
           Optionally, required minimum and maximum operational states can be specified after a
           colon ":". Please see networkctl(1) for possible operational states. If the
           operational state is not specified here, then the value from RequiredForOnline= in the
           corresponding .network file is used if present, and "degraded" otherwise.


The takeaway is, Network interface to wait for before deciding if the system is online. So this means that systemd-networkd-wait-online is waiting for interface enp0s3 to be at the required minimum state of degraded. The manpage for networkctl(1) states the following:

           degraded
               The link has carrier and addresses valid on the local link configured. For bond or
               bridge master this means that not all slave network interfaces have carrier but at
               least one does.


Yet you don't have an interface named enp0s3, which is shown with the output of networkctl status enp0s3. So I suspect that this misconfiguration is causing the state of your networking to fail.
To fix, remove the override file with the following:
sudo rm /etc/systemd/system/systemd-networkd-wait-online.service.d/override.conf

Then reload the systemd process so that it no longer references this override file:
sudo systemctl daemon-reload

